# problems with node.js and requests?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Thanks for the answer to [node.js and HTML page? How to combine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47514484/node-js-and-html-page-how-to-combine)
! That helped me to find out what to do: I now simply load my html-page in the node program and send it back at the first request. So my browser now has the page and requests can be sent via Javascript from there. That works fine now!

Maybe one can help me with these questions?

- What method in the req object gives me the URL of the requesting message?
- Is it possible to reach the node server also from outside the local net  and do communication?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**1)**

> **req.baseUrl**

or maybe just req.url, the best way to know it is:

```
console.log(request)
```

inside your function, and then you will see the request object

**2)**
To access your node serve you must be on the sabe network to 'see' the server.  That means that if your server is running in your computer at home, only computers in your network can reach the server. (You could 'open' your local network to the internet but I think that is not what you are looking for)

You can also host your server on the internet and, of course, anyone could reach the server.

Comment: maybe i was not specific enough!? I meant the id (e.g. "x.x.x.x") of the requesting client as a string!
In the meantime i found the method "req.connection.remoteAddress" which does what i want! Thanks.

Comment: 2) You are right!.